# Batch file to copy only the one newest file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to figure out a good way of doing this:

1. Files are created in an archive folder and we need to copy them to an FTP folder
2. The FTP folder does not retain files (the vendor picks them up and removes them)
3. Relevant files follow the same naming convention, but they are not the only files in either directory (e.g. namingconvetion_date is the filename)
4. I only want the one latest file matching the naming convention moved

What we are trying to avoid is a "bug" where all files in the archive that match the naming convention get moved, which causes our vendor to print old files.

The current copy command uses namingconvention*, which doesn't work because of the above bug.

Sample file formatting:   Vendor_MP_Summary02162015103001.csv
So it's MMDDYYYYHHMMSS date format

Easiest way to determine the latest would be by modified by on the files.

Comment: Can you include a sample of real file naming? What is the date format? How do you determine which is the newest file, by file name or file properties?

Comment: added information above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%a in ('
        dir /o-d /b /a-d "Vendor_MP_Summary*.csv" 
        ^| (set /p "file=" ^& call echo("%%file%%"^)
    ') do set "lastFile=%%~a"

    echo %lastFile%
```

Or

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%a in ('
        dir /o-d /b /a-d "Vendor_MP_Summary*.csv" 
    ') do set "lastFile=%%~a" & goto :found

:found
    echo %lastFile%
```

In both codes, the list of files is retrieved inside a `for /f` command with the help of a `dir` command to list the matching files in descending date order, so the newer file is the first one. To only retrieve this line from the full list

- in the first code a pipe to a `set /p` command is used, so only one line is retrieved from the list of files and returned to the `for /f`
- in the second case the full list is returned to the `for /f` and after retrieving the first line, a `goto` is used to skip processing the rest of the list

Comment: It works.  Thanks!  BTW, is there a resource you recommend to learn more about windows command line and bat files?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus [Rob van der Woude's scripting pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php), [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/), [dostips](http://www.dostips.com), and, of course, stackoverflow.

Comment: In case it might be helpful, DOS commands often have online help accessed by using `/?` as an example, `DIR /?` will display help for the `DIR` command.  This will reveal any command line switches that might be available.  These are especially important for use in batch files.